# Nginx not running. no such file or directory message -Mac

Tags: macos, nginx

I ran brew install nginx and when run 'nginx' I get this msg

```
nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.8.0/logs/proxy.access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

looking at /usr/local I see an nginx folder exists in '/etc/nginx' and also '/Cellar/nginx'.

What am I suppose to do?

Answer (score 6):

Resolved in two steps,

1. Create directory

   ```
   sudo mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.xx.xx/logs
   ```
2. Now create access.log file

   ```
   sudo touch /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.xx.xx/logs/access.log
   ```

As both operations involved with system files, I had to use `sudo`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the file cannot be opened because it doesn't exist; try creating it with:

```
touch /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.8.0/logs/proxy.access.log
```

More importantly make sure you are using `sudo` when you run `nginx`

```
sudo nginx
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had to create the **logs** directory inside the *hinted* folde.

```
mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.12.1/logs
```

and all the logs got created.